# Most efficient way of splitting many strings

Tags: c#, regex, string

My current project handles large numbers of incoming radio messages (~5M per day) represented as strings that must be then divided into pre-determined sized chunks, ready for storage.

For example, a message will come in the following format:

`mzIIIICCssss`

Each different char represents a chunk, so this example holds 5 chunks (m, z, IIII, CC, ssss).

An example of a message using the format could be:

`.91234NE0001` (., 9, 1234, NE, 0001)

I've used `substring` so far but have been told this is not as efficient as say regular expressions. If this is the case, how can I use `regex` to match at char positions, instead of a semantic pattern?

Comment: The format of the incoming messages is unclear.  Will they always need chunking into the exact same length?

Comment: I don't think a regex will be faster than plain `Substring` calls.

Comment: _"have been told"_ - don't believe rumours, use benchmarks.

Comment: @RoadieRich yes, the messages are always fixed in size.

Comment: depends on how your messages are formated, show us one example

Comment: @Eun I have, let me clarify further.

Comment: What means "extract", what is the desired result at all? Show your substring approach.

Comment: @TimSchmelter It's a simple task. The message is split so that each chunk can be stored in a db table column, as each chunk in the string represents something. So my question is: what's the best way to do it, resource wise?

Comment: If performance is so critical, why use a string at all? Go all the way down and use `byte[]`

Answer (score 5):

`Substring` is much faster than a regex. Since all you are trying to do is separate a string into fixed-size chunks, just use `Substring`.

---

cHao's comment gave me another idea. You could use the `string(char[], int, int)` constructor, somewhat like this:

```
string message = ".91234NE0001";
char[] messageArr = message.ToCharArray();
string chunk1 = new string(messageArr, 0, 1);
string chunk2 = new string(messageArr, 1, 1);
string chunk3 = new string(messageArr, 2, 4);
string chunk4 = new string(messageArr, 6, 2);
string chunk5 = new string(messageArr, 8, 4);
```

You can probably give the variables better names :)

This is the manual way of doing what `Substring` is doing. I thought it would be faster than the `Substring` method, but I was thinking of the wrong approach previously. It will probably be about the same speed.

Comment: Just a comment imho even if it's true.

Comment: @TimSchmelter It answers the question as I understand it.

Comment: So string immutability when using substring is not a real issue?

Comment: @Lee: Strings' immutability could actually help here -- since the string won't change, the substrings could just be offset into the main string's underlying `char[]`.  (Not sure whether .net does that; it might just be Java.)

Comment: @Lee Not really, no. With very very large strings, it *may* be more efficient to use a regex (because of computational complexity), but for 12 characters, it's certainly faster to use `Substring`.

Comment: Actually, I was thinking of the wrong algorithm for `Substring`, which was O(n^2). With the right algorithm, it will always be faster than a regex.

Comment: @KendallFrey Out of curiosity, is that "will always be faster than" or "will always be no slower than"?

Comment: @EricFinn I can't imagine that the regex would ever be as fast as `Substring`. I think it's safe to say that it "will always be faster than" the regex.

Answer (score 3):

I think the most efficient that you'll be able to achieve without dropping to native code is with unsafe code.

```
private static IEnumerable<string> ExtractChunksUnsafe(string format, string data)
{
    if(format.Length != data.Length)
        throw new ArgumentException("Format length must match Data length");

    if(data.Length == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Data length");

    char prevFormat = '\0';
    char currentFormat = format[0];

    var chunks = new List<string>();
    var builder = new StringBuilder();

    unsafe
    {
        fixed(char * indexer = data)
        {
            var index = -1;

            while(data.Length > ++index)
            {
                prevFormat = currentFormat;
                currentFormat = format[index];

                if(currentFormat != prevFormat)
                {
                    chunks.Add(builder.ToString());
                    builder.Clear();
                }

                builder.Append((*(indexer + index)));
            }

            chunks.Add(builder.ToString());
            builder.Clear();
        }
    }

    return chunks;
}
```

Comparison:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> ExtractChunks(string format, string data)
{
    if(format.Length != data.Length)
        throw new ArgumentException("Format length must match Data length");

    if(data.Length == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Data length");

    char prevFormat = '\0';
    char currentFormat = format[0];

    var prevIndex = 0;
    var index = 1;

    var message = data.ToCharArray();
    var chunks = new List<string>();

    while(data.Length > index)
    {
        prevFormat = currentFormat;
        currentFormat = format[index];

        if(currentFormat != prevFormat)
        {
            chunks.Add(new string(message, prevIndex, index - prevIndex));
            prevIndex = index;
        }

        index++;
    }

    chunks.Add(new string(message, prevIndex, index - prevIndex));

    return chunks;
}
```

Sample:

```
string format = "mzIIIICCssss";
string data = ".a9876NE9001";

var chunks = ExtractChunks(format, data);

foreach(var message in chunks)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```

Benchmark:

```
string format = "mzIIIICCssss";
string data = ".a9876NE9001";

// Warmup CLR
ExtractChunksUnsafe(format, data);
ExtractChunks(format, data);

TimeSpan unsafeCode;
TimeSpan safeCode;

var timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();

for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
{
    ExtractChunksUnsafe(format, data);
}

unsafeCode = timer.Elapsed;
timer.Restart();

for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
{
    ExtractChunks(format, data);
}

safeCode = timer.Elapsed;
timer.Stop();


Console.WriteLine("Unsafe time {0}", unsafeCode);
Console.WriteLine("Safe time {0}", safeCode);
```

Result:

```
Unsafe time 00:00:04.8551136
Safe time 00:00:03.1786573
```

Even modifying the Unsafe body:

```
unsafe
{
    fixed(char * indexer = data)
    {
        var prevIndex = 0;
        var index = 1;

        while(data.Length > index)
        {
            prevFormat = currentFormat;
            currentFormat = format[index];

            if(currentFormat != prevFormat)
            {
                chunks.Add(new string(indexer, prevIndex, index - prevIndex));
                prevIndex = index;
            }

            index++;
        }

        chunks.Add(new string(indexer, prevIndex, index - prevIndex));
    }
}
```

Will still result in slower time `Unsafe time 00:00:03.4565302`.

Comment: Isn't this sort of... overkill?

Comment: He said he wanted efficient. There's nothing more efficient than directly extracting the characters.

Comment: @KendallFrey It turns out the `unsafe` code is still slower than the safe code.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring questions of which solution is most efficient, here is a regex that will match the format given in the question (`mzIIIICCssss`)

```
(?<m>.)(?<z>.)(?<IIII>.{4})(?<CC>.{2})(?<ssss>.{4})
```

This will capture one character in a group called "m", the next character in a group called "z", the next 4 characters in a group called "IIII", the next 2 in "CC", and the next 4 in "ssss".

As far as performance, if the code you have right now isn't fast enough, and you've determined the string handling is the problem by profiling it, then look for faster replacements.